# Is it normal to these Xcode prompts/errors when you deploy to IOS Simulator from Unity?

Tags: unity, ios

Just trying out the IOS build process....

Is it normal to see:

Q1 - "upgrade to latest project format - project currently in Xcode 3.1 format, this will upgrade to 3.2" - just click OK and let Xcode do it's stuff?

Q2 - same as Q1 but this time for the message "Remove obsolete build settings - will remove the build setting PREBINDING"

Q3 - also when deploying to "Lastest IOS Simulator" you get the Simulator target produced, but also a non-simulator target which has lots of errors.  So I assume you just ignore this target and not use it in Xcode correct?  (i.e. just use the simulator target that is produced)

Q4 - get a lot of warning after the simulator target is built?  program works ok however....

*Images*

For Q1 and Q2:
[image]

For Q4:

Settings used in Unity:

[image]

Errors I see in XCode:
[image]

Comment: I think you would more readily find help at [Stack Overflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com). This isn't directly game related.

Comment: I don't know if I agree with that.  It's pretty game engine specific.

Answer (score 1):

In your Unity settings, try setting "SDK Version" to 4.0 and "Target iOS Version" to 3.2.1.